# Dependency tree doesn't give versions-maven-plugin source

Tags: maven, versions-maven-plugin

I am using below command to identify `versions-maven-plugin` source, since the specified plugin has not been directly defined in the project. But it doesn't show any details related to the said plugin.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

However below command gives the plugin info

```
mvn -Dplugin=org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin help:describe
```

Results:

```
Name: Versions Maven Plugin
Description: The Versions Maven Plugin is used when you want to manage the
  versions of artifacts in a project's POM.
Group Id: org.codehaus.mojo
Artifact Id: versions-maven-plugin
Version: 2.14.1
Goal Prefix: versions
```

Further I was trying to override the version by adding below into the project main pom. However same previous version (i.e. `2.14.1`) shows plugin describe results.

```
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.13.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
...
```

Comment: The `dependency:tree`only shows the dependencies of your project is not related to the plugins version... and what do you mean by: `doesn't give versions-maven-plugin source`?

Comment: @khmarbaise As described in the question the plugin has not been defined in the project. So my requirement is to check where it is coming from. Because override it with lower version also not accepted.

Comment: Without a full pom file it's impossible to even guess...

Comment: What says `mvn -Dplugin=org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.13.0 help:describe` (setting the version explicitly) ? The [doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/describe-mojo.html#plugin) is very clear regarding "input"(parameters) but not regarding "output" (/version used)